# Dash on Ubuntu 14.10 is slow on my Dell Studio 1558

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I just upgraded to the the Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) from Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) and the dash is running slow and freezes every now and then.

I don't really want to go back to 14.04 since I would have to start from the beginning, and I just went through the process of getting the OS to work with my hardware. Is there anything I can do to make my computer work better with the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable few results that you dont need much:

- install Unity Tweak Tool

launch it. and open Search

1. disable 'background blur'
2. uncheck 'search online sources'
3. uncheck 'show "more suggestions"'
4. uncheck 'show "recently used" applications'
5. uncheck "enable search of your files" => this is must for more apparent speed up

you can skip any of these if you want.

---

if this does not works you can try light desktop environments like KDE and XFCE. you can install this from software center. install them and log out and select the session and login again.

[image: ubuntu login screen, select session]

[image: select kde desktop on login]

Comment: @DevinIce you can try lite desktop from ubuntu software center; like kde desktop, dont use unity; unity is resource eater

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have enough disk space for your home files or computer storage that runs the ubuntu software. I had the same issue once when I first installed ubuntu on a 7GB partition. But after I increased the disk size/storage it works fine and no freezing. I run a 32-bit laptop, with 2GB RAM and I am enjoying ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: ubuntu is the only operating system with 4gb of ram and 500gb HDD and 64bit now 14.04 ran without any problems other than i couldnt adjust brightness but i googled that issue and got that resolved thats why i dont want to go back to 14.04 due to the first time i tried to fix the brightness i crashed the computer and had to a clean install on my laptop.

Comment: How much space did you give it?